# unknow `runcrons` when running `python3 manage.py runcrons

Tags: django, django-cron

When I run `python3 manage.py runcrons`, this message appears: "Unknown command: 'runcrons'". I run `python3 manage.py help` and couldn't find runcrons in the list of commands. How can I add `runcrons` to `manage.py`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJaiy.png)

Comment: `runcrons` is apparently a [`django-cron`](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) command. Have you followed those linked installation instructions?

Comment: I tried running `python manage.py migrate django_cron` as instructed here: https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html but then got this error: "CommandError: No installed app with label 'django_cron'.". I did add django_cron to INSTALLED_APP and there is django_cron in my lib folder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.